# pipe text stream to eval in terminal

Tags: terminal, environment-variables

So I have a bunch of environment variables I am getting from netlify where I store them and I pipe them into an .env.local file, and then when I start my process it reads that .env.local file, but unfortunately the process also updates when the env file updates. What I would like is to pipe those environment variables so that they are evaluated in the terminal and only avaialable there, so I can pipe variables from version A into one terminal and variables from version B into another terminal.

it's not too important but here is the current code

```
netlify env:list --plain true > ../env.local
```

So, hoping to keep it short and sweet, how to do that?